# Silverlight client computer name, user name or a unique key from client

Tags: wcf, silverlight, client, computer-name

I'm trying to get a unique key from client such username or computer name but on wcf side none of the following works for me:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name // blank
Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

I'm using Anonymous mode for security and user shouldn't be logged on anyway. How can I do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using anonymous authentication mode, then a blank Name is what you get.
As the mode implies, the request is kind of.... anonymous.

If a unique identifier is what you need, I think your best bet in this scenario would be to add a custom header to your request containing a Guid created at first run and preserved in isolated storage.

Comment: Could you please give me a sample code to get mac adress from silverlight.

Comment: Touché. Not easily done in sandbox mode without using pinvoke in trusted mode. I've updated with an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you can guarantee unique IP addresses (*not likely, but possible*):

You could try accessing the [`Request.ServerVariables` to retrieve the consumers IP Address](http://www.whadiz.com/what-is.aspx/programming/visual-c-sharp-in-asp-dot-net/visitor-ip-address)?

Here's a [list of common **Server Variable Keys**](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp).

#### If you cannot guarantee unique IP addresses:

[This SL forum post suggests using a GUID kept in isolated storage](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/207029/486196.aspx) that is sent back and forth for context.

Comment: Thanks SilverNinja but a local or remote ip can change easly.

Comment: Correct - it depends on how the Silverlight client is consumed.